# NSlog does not print new lines \r\n

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to add new lines to `NSlog`.

I run:

```
NSLog(@"\n%@\r\n\r\n", json1);
NSLog(@"\n%@\r\n\r\n", json2);
```

However The output is:

```
2017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527]  
{"attribution":"true"}
2017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527]  
{"attribution":"false"}
```

It ignores new line as `\r\n` (tried also `\n` only) but 1st `\n` before string works

I expect:

```
2017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527]  
{"attribution":"true"}


2017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527]  
{"attribution":"false"}


017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527] other logs ...
```

I use Xcode 8.3

**[Edit 1]**

I tried to run:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@",type, @"xxxxx\n\n");
```

Still I see:

```
2017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527]  
xxxxx
017-03-29 16:09:50 InAppTestAfApp2[312:33527] other logs ...
```

**[EDIT 2]**

As work around I add garbage at the end but it looks messy:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@\r\n\r\n%s",type, json, @"`");
```

Answer (score 6):

Carriage return/linefeed pairs (CR+LF) have never been needed on the Mac. Classic MacOS used CR, and MacOS X uses LF (due to its Unix heritage). So it's not surprising that `NSLog()` strips the CR characters out of the text that you're logging.

It's also not surprising that `NSLog()` trims the white space from the end of your log statements. `NSLog()` is meant for *logging* messages -- it's not a general-purpose `print` statement. Keeping logs compact is useful, and trimming blank lines from the end of a message serves that purpose.

If you really want to include blank space in your messages, perhaps to make certain log messages stand out more, you can do it by including a printing character after the blank lines. For example:

```
    NSLog(@"\n\nMy Really Important Message\n\n.");
```

The result:

```
2017-03-29 09:28:12.898 MessageTest[13407:2524935] 

My Really Important Message

.
```