# Quirk disappearing white space string

Tags: objective-c

I run into this funny situation. I create a string containing only white space. Spaces and newlines. No matter if I create it randomly or using a loop inside a loop (lots of spaces followed by a newline). When I log the string it does not show up? Even the newline in

```
NSLog(@"String\n%@",s);
```

disappears. If I add anything that is not whitespace to `s` then it shows up.

Here is the code to reproduce it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString * func ( BOOL f )
{
    // Create a string containing only white space
    NSMutableString * s = NSMutableString.string;
    BOOL rand = NO;

    if ( rand )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 500; i ++ )
        {
            if ( arc4random_uniform(100) > 90 )
            {
                [s appendString:@"\n"];
            }
            else
            {
                [s appendString:@" "];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j ++ )
            {
                [s appendString:@" "];
            }

            [s appendString:@"\n"];
        }
    }

    if ( f )
    {
        [s appendString:@"?\n"];
    }

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        NSLog(@"The string is\n%@",func(NO));

        NSLog(@"Where is it?");

        // Now add something real
        NSLog(@"The string is\n%@",func(YES));
        NSLog(@"Oh there it is?");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note in main the first time `func` is called with `BOOL` `NO` as argument, the function just creates a bunch of whitespace. So I'd expect to see it in the log. However, the log shows nothing! Not even the newline!

Then I call the function again. This time it generates the same thing but postfixes it with a question mark and suddenly the string appears. Where did the whitespace go? Is there some funny optimisation going on? Looks like a bug.

Here is the output for reference.

```
2021-01-23 21:28:43.990972+0200 WhiteSpaceString[33439:733772] Hello, World!
2021-01-23 21:28:43.991845+0200 WhiteSpaceString[33439:733772] The string is
2021-01-23 21:28:43.991943+0200 WhiteSpaceString[33439:733772] Where is it?
2021-01-23 21:28:43.992171+0200 WhiteSpaceString[33439:733772] The string is
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
?
2021-01-23 21:28:43.997993+0200 WhiteSpaceString[33439:733772] Oh there it is?
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Initially I thought maybe the function is to blame, as it returns a string but internally uses a mutable string. But even if the code is put inside main e.g.

```
        NSMutableString * t = NSMutableString.string;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j ++ )
            {
                [t appendString:@" "];
            }

            [t appendString:@"\n"];
        }

        NSLog(@"The string is\n%@",t);
```

it still does not show the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSlog does not print new lines \r\n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094610/nslog-does-not-print-new-lines-r-n)

Comment: @Willeke thanks - not really ... . It says e.g. "Keeping logs compact is useful..." and seems more of an argument for this type of behaviour rather than explaining it. But, like that answer, I figure this must be Xcode's logging behaviour. Any docs to back it up would be useful, I could not find anything and that answer doesn't give any.